# Exception when trying to add users to demo tenant (C#)

Tags: c#, graph, microsoft-graph-api

I have the following code for adding users to my demo tenant:

```
    public class Users
    {
        private static readonly AzureADUser[] _testUsers = new AzureADUser[AppSettings.LoadAppSettings().UserCount];
        private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient = null;

        public Users(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
        {
            _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
        }
        public async Task addUsers()
        {
            var users = await _graphServiceClient.Users.Request().Filter("startswith(MailNickname, 'testuser')").GetAsync();            
            for (int i = 0; i < _testUsers.Length; i++)
            {
                if (_testUsers[i] == null)
                    await AddNewUser(i);
            }           
        }

        private static readonly DemoData _preprodGraphUsers = new DemoData();
        private async Task AddNewUser(int number)
        {
            var csvUser = _preprodGraphUsers.GetMockUserInfo(number);
            var user = new User
            {
                DisplayName = $"Test User {number}",
                // UserPrincipalName = "user principal name",
                // OnPremisesImmutableId = "immutable id"
            };

            _testUsers[number] = ToEntity(await _graphServiceClient.Users.Request().AddAsync(user));
        }

        private static AzureADUser ToEntity(User user)
        {
            return new AzureADUser() { ObjectId = Guid.Parse(user.Id) };
        }
    }
```

On running the code, the execution stops at this line:

```
_testUsers[number] = ToEntity(await _graphServiceClient.Users.Request().AddAsync(user));
```

I see the following exception in the output window:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Share the error message and response code.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you have to specify more than DisplayName property.

The following properties are required when you create a user.
[image]

[Create user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)